# Brightway2: how to retrieve a specific activity by name

Tags: python, brightway

I am new to all this so please be patient.

I've initialized a new BW2 installation and added an Ecoinvent database (some output trimmed for clarity):

```
>>> from brightway2 import bw2setup, Database, SingleOutputEcospold2Importer
>>> bw2setup()
>>> ei = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer('/path/to/datasets', 'ei3.4 cutoff')
>>> ei.apply_strategies()
>>> ei.statistics()
14889 datasets
520205 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
>>> ei.write_database()
```

So far, so good (note in particular the number of datasets loaded).  But now- how do I use it?  TO be specific, I would like to retrieve the process entitled `market for transport, freight, lorry, unspecified` with `GLO` spatial scope.  But I don't know the key for this activity, and surprisingly, it doesn't show up in a search

```
>>> Database('ei3.4 cutoff').search('market for transport, freight, lorry, unspecified')
[]
>>> Database('ei3.4 cutoff').search('market for transport')
[]
```

!! Very surprising, no markets for transport? By inspection I can see that there are 139 activities beginning with the phrase `market for transport` in Ecoinvent 3.4 cutoff.

In fact, although there are 3,966 "market" processes in EI 3.4 cutoff, my brightway install only knows about two dozen:

```
>>> Database('ei3.4 cutoff').search('market')
['market for paris market carrot' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'paris market carrot production' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for acetonitrile' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for sulfur' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for whey' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for heptane' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for straw' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for clay' (kilogram, CH, None),
 'market for pitch' (kilogram, CH, None),
 'market for brass' (kilogram, CH, None),
 'market for platinum' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for polycarbonate' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for pitch' (kilogram, RoW, None),
 'market for tetrafluoroethylene' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for dimethenamide' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for glyphosate' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for styrene' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for ferrite' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for folpet' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for magnetite' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for metamitron' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for nylon 6-6' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for atrazine' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for magnesium' (kilogram, GLO, None),
 'market for metaldehyde' (kilogram, GLO, None)]
```

How do I find a dataset that does not show up in a search?  Rather unhelpfully, the documentation appears to *strictly* use `random()` to retrieve activities (e.g. here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/Databases.ipynb) which does not help me answer this question.

So- two questions-

1. how do I find the activity of interest, `market for transport, freight, lorry, unspecified [GLO]`?
2. Why is my database missing around 3,940 markets, according to the search?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use list comprehensions to realize your search. It should be quite efficient.

`db_bd = bw.Database('ei3.4 cutoff')`

```
market_brandon_want = [act for act in db_bd 
                    if 'market for transport, freight, lorry, unspecified' in act['name'] 
                    and 'GLO' in act['location']
     ][0]
```

2. Then if you do:

`len([act for act in db_bd if 'market' in act['name'] ])`

You should get 4183, which seems to be a more accurate number. I am sure that you could refine your filter to get closer to your number.

You can follow the teaching material from the [Brightway2 seminar](https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017) held in Zürich in 2017. This was really helpful in my case.

Comment: I indeed get the same numbers as you- though `act['name'].startswith('market')` is a better way to find markets- and there are 3,966 of them - the other 217 are not market processes.

Answer (score 1):

Try including more keywords in the search field **without comma**.

```
Database("ecoinvent 3.4 conseq").search('market transport freight lorry unspecified')
```

In my version returns:

```
['transport, freight, lorry, all sizes, EURO3 to generic market for 
transport, freight, lorry, unspecified' (ton kilometer, RER, None), 
'transport, freight, lorry, all sizes, EURO3 to generic market for transport, 
freight, lorry, unspecified' (ton kilometer, RoW, None),
'transport, freight, lorry, all sizes, EURO4 to generic market for transport, 
freight, lorry, unspecified' (ton kilometer, RoW, None),
'transport, freight, lorry, all sizes, EURO5 to generic market for transport, 
freight, lorry, unspecified' (ton kilometer, RoW, None),
...
```

You can use filters to find the location as well:

```
Database("ecoinvent 3.4 conseq").search('market transport freight lorry unspecified', filter={"location" : 'GLO'})
```

returns:

```
['market for transport, freight, lorry, unspecified' (ton kilometer, GLO, None)]
```

Not sure this will work if you want to automatise the search, (e.g. to find the code of a series of processes).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to exclude commas- I guess there is some cleverness going on with the search function.

Answer (score 1):

1) I always use list comprehension as Laurent. Note that activities have a field called *activity type*. The possible values are 'market activity', 'market group', 'ordinary transforming activity'

```
db_bd = bw.Database('ei3.4 cutoff')
set([ds['activity type'] for ds in bd_db])
```

This field is useful to distinguish markets and ordinary transforming activities

```
market_brandon_want = [act for act in db_bd
                if 'freight, lorry, unspecified' in act['name'] 
                and 'GLO' in act['location']
                and act['activity type']!='ordinary transforming activity'
 ]
market_brandon_want
```

2) search does not find all the markets because there is a limit to the number of results. You can change it with the argument limit ([documentation](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2data.html?highlight=search#bw2data.backends.peewee.database.SQLiteBackend.search)).

```
bw.Database('ei3.4 cutoff').search('market',limit=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, one obvious approach that works is to use the database's built-in iterator:

```
>>> m_t_f_l_u = next(_a for _a in Database('ei3.4 cutoff') \
                     if _a['name'] == 'market for transport, freight, lorry, unspecified' \
                     and _a['location'] == 'GLO')
```

This works.  It doesn't seem very efficient, though, and it takes several seconds to run.

Comment: It should be considerably faster in subsequent runs. 

Brightway is designed to support numerous workflows, including the addition of arbitrary data to activities; therefore you need to iterate over each row and parse it into Python to support "general-purpose" searching. In this particular case, you could use the ORM:

 from bw2data.backends.peewee.proxies import Activity, ActivityDataset as AD;
 act = Activity(AD.select().where(
  AD.name == 'market for transport, freight, lorry, unspecified', 
  AD.location == 'GLO'
 ).get())